# How do I get images to publish to Azure through VSTS (Azure DevOps) build pipelines

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, asp.net-core-2.1

I've added several images to the wwroot/images folder for an asp.net core MVC project.  They are included and displaying just fine locally, however when they are published through the AzureDevOps pipeline the images aren't appearing.

I've looked at the wwroot in Kudu and determined that the files aren't in the images directory in Azure, and I looked in the build command line results in AzureDevOps and I can see that the copy command for those images isn't being run during the MSBuild, but the original banner.svg images from the base project template are being copied.

I did a search files and saw that there was a file called project.assets.json which has include statements for the original images, but not the images I've added to the project.  I suspect that the issue lies with the new images not being added to the project.assets.json file. This file appears to be auto generated though.  I've verfieid that the new images have a build action of "Content" and I've even tried setting to copy always but to no avail.  I'm thinking there is something else I need to do to get those files to be included in the project.assets.json on build.

Anyone know how to get new images to be added and recognized through the build script in Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that if you add the images to the wwroot folder, they are added to your local wwroot but never added to the wwroot folder that's in source control.  I went and added the images that were missing to the wwroot/images folder in source control and check them in.  Afterwards the publish went through without issue.  I tried copy/pasting to the images folder and going right click > add > existing item and both did not recognize the add operation as a pending change in source. Not sure if this is a bug in VS or what.

Answer (score 1):

More than likely it’s your csproj file not having the right element to include those files in publish. Try doing a dot net publish locally  and see if the files show up in the output directory .  If they do then you only need to run that same.net publish command at the same commit.  If they do not, then you need to update your CS project file to include those files ,  then retry dotnet publish locally to verify issue was resolved